# Convert java.util.Date object into a Windows FILETIME structure

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I have a Java application and I need to call into a Windows DLL using JNA.  The function I need to call actually takes a `__int64` (internally it splits this into low/high portions of the `FILETIME` structure).  Given a `java.util.Date` object, how can I convert it to the appropriate value formatted for a `FILETIME`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JNA provides some static methods on the [FILETIME](http://jna.java.net/javadoc/platform/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinBase.FILETIME.html) class which is located in the Platform jar.

```
FILETIME.dateToFileTime( Date date );
FILETIME.filetimeToDate( int high, int low );
```

Comment: The JavaDoc for JNA's FILETIME support has moved to https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinBase.FILETIME.html

Answer (score 5):

This is how you can do it using Java nio

```
    BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(filePath, BasicFileAttributes.class);
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Date d = new Date(attr.creationTime().toMillis()); //attr.creationTime() returns a FileTime             
    System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I figured it out:

```
long date = (new Date().getTime() + 11644473600000L) * 10000L;
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea. I would never have been thougth of that. Many-many thanks.

Comment: care to elaborate on how you came up with `11644473600000L`?

Comment: @HairOfTheDog It's the offset from the 1601 Epoch ([Windows FILETIME base](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa915351(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)) to the 1970 Epoch (Unix time), in milliseconds.  369 years which included 89 leap years, so 369L * 365L + 89L) * 86400L * 1000L